# ProgrammingError at / relation does not exist

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I can not find answer in other places. (Sorry for asking again but)

what is wrong?
Did anyone have such an error?

> ProgrammingError at /register/
>   relation "user_user" does not exist
>   LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "user_user" WHERE "user_user"."userna...

I extended user abstract model and error saying no relation
When i extend user in sqlite3 no errors such this but postgre is full databse error

```
 class User(AbstractUser):
    social_username = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
def registration(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request,'You were successfully registered  %s' % user.first_name)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        messages.error(request, 'Something went wrong while authenticating')
        return render(request, 'project/register.html', {'form': form})

    else:
        form = RegisterUserForm()
        return render(request, 'project/register.html', {'form': form})
```

settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user.User'
```

Comment: You probably forget to run `makemigrations` and `migrate`

Comment: I already did it 100 times

Comment: I tried to everything with migrations deleted them and runed commands again , recreated table User

Comment: If you don't care about the data, try to delete your entire database and run `migration` again. Sometimes django thought it did migration but didn't actually, usually happens after you manually changed some db entries.

Comment: I got rid of some of the problems that were in the sqlite3 database deletion method. It was easy to delete sqlite3 on menu toolbar just click to databse and delete, but how to delete or reset PostgreSql?

Comment: Can you please post the output of `migrate`?

Comment: I have the same problem do you have any answer

Comment: if yes please let me know

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why this error occurs but you could just run this command and you are good to go without losing your data.

```
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

Answer (score 0):

i delete migrations from user app reconnect to local db in pgAdmin4 makemigrations migrate and all works i tryed to migrate separete my site app and user so error was when i try migrate user app helped to me :) gl.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Delete existing migrations, drop the database and create it again(WITH THE SAME NAME), make new migrations and you're good to go

Comment: A solution that requires deleting migrations and _dropping the database_ doesn't seem like much of a solution.